# Scrollbar is overlayed on a Mac but is inline with content on Windows

Tags: css

I have a vertical scrollbar that is set to auto and only shows up when content is to be scrolled. My code is running on Chrome. By default Chrome overlays the scrollbar on top of the content and when it detects no mouse movements, makes the scrollbar disappear. But this appears to work only on a Mac. But when I run the same app on Windows, the scrollbar will show up but pushes the content to the left by the an amount that is the width of the scrollbar. This is bad behavior because it tends to make the content flicker. Is there a way that I can get the scrollbar to overlay on top of the content the same way it does on a Mac?

You can see this effect if you are running a Mac and just scroll this Stackoverflow post up to the top or down to the bottom. You'll notice that the scrollbar is overlayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you would have to "make your own scrollbar"

Check this article

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

But, from the article:

> Custom scrollbars are not supported in Firefox or IE/Edge.

Unless you REALLY have to make it look like on OS X, i would advise just to learn to live with the differences.

Comment: It's actually less about making it look like a Mac and making it look more consistent regardless what platform the app runs on. The app is actually an Electron app, so I want to have some consistency. If you look at Slack, it uses the same scrollbar on either platform. While I have figured out how to create custom scrollbars, getting it to overlay the content hasn't been successful. Then again, neither does Slack overlay theirs.

Comment: Check this library, maybe it can save you time: https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/

Comment: Awesome. I tried it out on Windows and it behaves the same as on a Mac. Thanks a million!

Comment: Actually, after downloading and testing, it requires that you modify your layout in order to work. This is problematic. Here's a jQuery plugin that doesn't require any modification to your html but gives the same results: http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing!